# Yesterday this was working but today it isn't

Tags: python

Yesterday I managed to get this code working however, when I went to try it today it just loops itself and I do not get why this does so.

Here is code:

```
global p1_final_score
global p2_final_score
global p1_round1_score
global p2_round1_score

print("player 1 turn")
player1_dice1_round1_dice = print(Fore.GREEN + "Round1/Player1: " + Fore.WHITE +
                                  input( "Press 1 to roll dice: "))
#timer delay which pauses before continuing to next line
time.sleep(0.25)
while player1_dice1_round1_dice != "1":
    player1_dice1_round1_dice = print(Fore.GREEN + "Round1/Player1: " + Fore.WHITE +
                                      input( "Press 1 to roll dice: "))
    time.sleep(0.25)
else:
    player1_dice1_round1_answer = random.randint(1, 6)
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("You rolled the first dice and the answer is: ",
          player1_dice1_round1_answer)
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

Full code here https://pastebin.com/K8fFQc0r

Comment: `print()` returns a `None` and `None` is always not equal to `"1"`. Don't blame *'today'*.

Comment: for advice use ide (example pycharm ) where you have a history of code. so you won't fall to this situation again

Comment: so how will I be able to fix this @Austin

Comment: What you want is not clear neither did you explain in your question. Anyway, because you say it worked yesterday, revert changes that you made today. :P

Answer (score 0):

change 
`player1_dice1_round2_dice = print(Fore.GREEN + "Round2/Player1: " + Fore.WHITE + input( "Press 2 to roll dice: "))`
to

`player1_dice1_round2_dice =  input(Fore.GREEN + "Round2/Player1: " + Fore.WHITE +"Press 2 to roll dice: ")`

perform same in all code.

ps: alternate, ctrl+Z will revert back all your changes . do this till you are in running state.